# Email array validation Adonis js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I am trying to validate the email array. Can I use this method validate for email, but I Can't Get Any result and I use adonis 4.1.0  I return mail_array_check it is getting an error message but all mails are correct it is getting correct mails.

```
const user = await auth.getUser();
const mails = request.all().mails;
const receivers_mails = JSON.parse(mails);
const mail_array_check = await receivers_mails.filter(async m => {
  const rules1 = {m: 'email'};
  const validation1 = await validateAll(m, rules1)
  if (validation1.fails()) {
    return response.status(400).send({status: false, message: validation1.messages()})
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( var  i=0; i < receivers_mails.length; i++){
  this.passMails = typeof `${receivers_mails[i]}` ==='string' && /^[\w+\d+._]+\@[\w+\d+_+]+\.[\w+\d+._]{2,8}$/.test(`${receivers_mails[i]}`);
  if(this.passMails === false){
    return response.status(400).send({
      message:"Invalid Sender email address, Please check sender email address!",
      status:false
    })
  }
}
```